# Can I use `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` to increase the concurrency of spark streaming jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I found the `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` in risk to caused that loss data and does not work with many features in the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21065) . Anyone knows that fixed or not?

Another question: Can I set the dependency that current batch depends on previous batch in spark streaming.